# Assert.Equal trying to cast ushort? to 'string'

Tags: c#, nullable, xunit.net, ushort

When a `ushort?` is passed to `Assert.Equal` it is trying to cast the two argumants to `string`. It works fine for `int?`. If I change the code to `ushort test = 10;` or  `Assert.Equal((ushort)10, test);` or `Assert.Equal(10, (ushort)test);` it works fine. Whats the reason for that? Can it be because of `ushort` and both `char` is 2 bytes and `Assert.Equal` is implicitly trying to treat the `ushort?` as a string?

[image]

Comment: Which specific `Assert.Equal` are you _expecting_ it to call (so we can explain why it doesn't choose it)? https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/main/EqualityAsserts.cs

Comment: The short answer is that generic resolution won't / can't find a type T that accepts both `int` and `ushort?`. So it knows that a ushort can be passed as a int, or a int? can be passed as an int - but it doesn't "know" that both a ushort? and an int can be passed as a int?.

Comment: `10` is `int`. `10L` would be `long`, `10d` would be `double` and `10m` would be `decimal`. Seems like there is no literal for (u)short, though. And there apparently isn't an implicit way to cast `int` to `ushort?`. So this assert is trying to find another way to compare the values. Apparently by trying to call a method that expects two strings.

Comment: You can repro this with a little sample yourself if you'd like - https://dotnetfiddle.net/NoqNDD .

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that although there is an implicit conversion from `10` to `ushort?`

```
ushort? foo = 10;
```

This only works because the constant expression `10` is within the range of `ushort`, and an [implicit constant expression conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-constant-expression-conversions) is applied.

---

The `Equal` method group has generic methods, like [the one that you are trying to call](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/main/EqualityAsserts.cs#L58). So before overload resolution can begin, [type inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#type-inference) occurs.

> Type inference occurs as part of the binding-time processing of a method invocation and takes place before the overload resolution step of the invocation. When a particular method group is specified in a method invocation, and no type arguments are specified as part of the method invocation, type inference is applied to each generic method in the method group. [...] If type inference for a particular method fails, that method does not participate in overload resolution.

In this case, type inference actually fails for all the generic overloads, so they don't take part in overload resolution. `Equal(string, string)` is one of the overloads that *do*. That's why the error message is about the string overload.

Why does type inference fail? Because there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `ushort?` or from `ushort?` to `int`. Type inference only cares about the types of the arguments, the parameters, and the type parameters. It doesn't care about whether the arguments are constant expressions or anything like that, so the aforementioned implicit constant expression conversion is not applicable. I encourage you to follow through the type inference process in the spec. It's great fun :)

See the references to "type of `Ei`" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-first-phase):

> For each of the method arguments `Ei`:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, if `Ei` has a *type* `U` and `xi` is a value parameter then a lower-bound inference is made from `U` to `Ti`.
> - [...]

Compare this to how it refers to "argument" rather than "type of argument" in [overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#applicable-function-member):

> For each argument in `A`, the parameter passing mode of the argument (i.e., value, `ref`, or `out`) is identical to the parameter passing mode of the corresponding parameter, and
>
> - for a value parameter or a parameter array, an implicit conversion exists from the argument to the type of the corresponding parameter, or
> - [...]

So it seems that overload resolution *does* look at the arguments' expressions, which is why it would have worked if you made the method non-generic, accepting two `ushort?`. In that case it does not participate in type inference, only overload resolution.

The reason why casting the `10` to `ushort` or `byte` works is because there does exist an implicit conversion between from `ushort` to `ushort?` and from `byte` to `ushort?`. This is done via an [implicit nullable conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-nullable-conversions).

Comment: @mjwills I rewrote the whole answer. Hopefully this time I figured it out :)

Comment: So, roughly speaking, it will work if the nullable one is the "broader" one, but not the "narrower" one?

Comment: @mjwills yes. That's what I found.

Comment: @Sweeper, thanks it makes a bit sense now :)

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCode If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!